# How to output in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I'm writing an Apex program that reads through a database and processes record. Each time I process a record, I want to output a message. Currently I'm using System.Debug to do this, but the debug log is cluttered with so much that this doesn't seem like the right approach.

What other ways can I generate screen or logfile output in SalesForce?

Answer (score 1):

Keep using `System.Debug()` but when you want to view only your output messages, just filter by `DEBUG`. Otherwise the only other option is to create a view and then that is more clutter than what it's worth.

Comment: Another option with the log it to set the LoggingLevel in each call. E.g. `System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Info, 'Testing');`. Then you can reduce the logging levels to info and still see your messages.

Comment: I usually put a prefix " --- " (three dashes) to find my output.

Comment: The debug messages are already prefixed with a DEBUG so the case sensitive filter just works

Comment: @GerardSexton, I'm too lazy to do use all that filters. And beside this, I usually want to see full picture rather than ONLY my output. Usually I want to highlight my output. Maybe Riothamus will fine my approach interesting even that he asked a bit other thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please Open the Log in Raw format under Setup>> Administration Setup >> Monitoring >>Debug Logs. Under **Monitored Users** go to **Filters** and enable all the filter levels. Now use apex code as given

```
System.debug('StackOverflow >>1234'+ e.getMessage)
```

and search the detailed debug logs for **StackOverflow >>1234** the unique message. It may also happen that your system.debug might not have been executed in that specific Debug logs so do not forget to check all the recent debug logs. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could think about creating your own Logging__c object.  And create a record for it for each record processed.  You have to be creative to work round the governor limits though.

If it's not essential that you output the message in between processing each record, then you could build up a collection of Logging__c records as processing continues and then either insert them periodically, or when there's an exception in your process.

Note that if inserting them periodically, you still have to make sure the jobs not so large that you're going to hit the DML limit of 150 together with the processing work you're doing.  Also, if storing the records to all be inserted at the end of processing, bear in mind the heap size is 6MB.

Alternatively, have a look at Batch Apex http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm

This allows you to create a class to handle processing a job in asynchronous chunks.  You can set the number of records processed in one go.  So you could set this small (~20) and then insert a Logging_*c  record as each job record is processed to stay within the Batch Apex DML limit of 200.  You can then monitor Logging*_c records in real time to view progress.